# Display Flutter Container at Bottom of Scaffold

Tags: flutter

I am looking for help in getting a container with an ad banner to display at the bottom of a Flutter scaffold. Instead, the container mistakenly displays directly underneath a card.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          xxx: xxx,
          child: Column(
            xxx: xxx,
            children: [
              InkWell(...),
              Card(...),
              Container(...)
           ],
          ),
         ),
        ),
       );
```

Comment: Try wrap the container an Align then set its alignment to bottom center.Or just Add beneath in the Card a space called Spacer();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a `Spacer()` between your `Card` and your last `Container` :

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          xxx: xxx,
          child: Column(
            xxx: xxx,
            children: [
              InkWell(...),
              Card(...),
              Spacer(),
              Container(...)
           ],
          ),
         ),
        ),
       );
```